# How to break a loop in all process with a flag in MPI?

Tags: c, linux, mpi

Well, I can't really figure how to fix this.

I have this array of ints, and lets say anywhere there is a "-1" in it is a free space to add a new number.

```
    aux=atoi(argv[2]);
    for(i=0;i<ctotal && f;i++){
        if(rank==liste[i]){
            if(list[i]==-1){
                list[i]=aux;
                f=0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically that is the piece of code.

There are two "lists" (In fact, they are just two arrays).

list is an array with numbers, the liste is an array with the same lenght as list but it contain the number of process in charge of the number in list.

**Example:**

```
list[5] = {1,1,2,2,3};
liste[5] = {0,0,1,1,2};
```

So that menas es process 0 is in charge of {1,1}, the process 1 is in charge of {2,2} and the process 2 is in charge of {3}.

Anyway, it actually works, but my problem is  I want to "break" the loop in all process when some process find the first free space (-1 in this case) and add the number to that space but I can't figure how.

I think I can't just use Bcast because I dont know what process found the first free space.

So what actually need is the first process to change f value to 0, share it with all process so all process break que loop

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this is to use `MPI_Allreduce` with a variable that stores `1` if the process has found the space and `0` otherwise. That is, have a variable `int foundSpace = 0;` set to `0` (not found) by default. If the process finds what you're looking for, set `foundSpace = 1`. When you're checking to see if any process has found `foundSpace`, do

```
int foundSpaceAny;
MPI_Allreduce(&foundSpace, &foundSpaceAny, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Note the `MPI_SUM` reduction operation. With this, if any of your processes found a space, `foundSpaceAny` will contain a non-zero value. If none of them did, `foundSpaceAny` will contain a 0. Use this check to break your loop.